# how to generalize a callable with params in java?

Tags: java, refactoring, runnable, callable

I have these two methods

```
private void saveBaseLineLatency(E2EResultShort e2EResultShort) {
    LatencyHistogram latencyHistogram = getLatencyHistogram(e2EResultShort);
    latencyDrillDownRepository.saveBaseLine(latencyHistogram);
    saveLatencyTable(latencyHistogram);
}

private void saveFreshTestLatency(E2EResultShort e2EResultShort) {
    System.out.println("log: before saveLatencyHistogram");
    LatencyHistogram latencyHistogram = getLatencyHistogram(e2EResultShort);
    latencyDrillDownRepository.save(latencyHistogram);
    saveLatencyTable(latencyHistogram);
}
```

How can I refactor out their common code?

I thought to use Callable but its `call()` is parameterless.

Comment: Can't you just use a helper method?

Answer (score 0):

[`Consumer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html) is the interface you want.  It's part of the new `java.util.function` package in Java 8, so this won't work if you're on an older version of Java.  (The package also has a number of similar other interfaces, like a `BiConsumer` that takes two arguments, and interfaces for consuming various primitive types as well.)

So, your helper method would be something like:

```
private void doLatencyOperation (E2EResultShort newThing, Consumer<LatencyHistogram> consumer) {
  LatencyHistogram lh = getLatencyHistogram(newThing);
  consumer.accept(lh);
  saveLatencyTable(lh);
}
```

and you could call it thusly

```
private void saveBaseLineLatency(E2EResultShort e2EResultShort) {
  doLatencyOperation(e2EResultShort, (lh) -> latencyDrillDownRepository.saveBaseLine(lh));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an abstract class and move all the common code there.

`public abstract class MyClass{`

```
public MyClass(E2EResultShort result, latencyDrillDownRepository){
    this.result = result;
}
```

`public void execute() {`

```
 LatencyHistogram latencyHistogram = getLatencyHistogram(e2EResultShort);
callMe(latencyHistogram, latencyDrillDownRepository);
saveLatencyTable(latencyHistogram);
```

}

`public abstract void callMe(LatencyHistogram latencyHistogram, latencyDrillDownRepository);`
}`

Now in your method, create concrete MyClass:

`private void saveFreshTestLatency(E2EResultShort e2EResultShort) {`

```
System.out.println("log: before saveLatencyHistogram");
MyClass myClass = new MyClass(e2EResultShort, latencyDrillDownRepository){
    public void callMe(LatencyHistogram latencyHistogram, latencyDrillDownRepository){
        latencyDrillDownRepository.save(latencyHistogram);
    }
}

myClass.execute();
```

`}`